# how can i verify if the username and password exists in my websql database for login page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

here's my login page code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Si Mohamed\Desktop\projects\game shop\jv.js">          
</script>
<title>E-keys Store</title>
</head>
<script>
function verify() {

var usrname = document.getElementById("usrname").values;
var pass = document.getElementById("pass").values;



if (usrname2 == usrname && pass2 == pass) {
alert("logged in successfully");

}else {

alert("account doesnt exist");
}
}

</script>
<body>
<form class="sign" action="index.html" method="post">


<div class="sign_in">
<p class="title">SIGN IN</p>
<p class="mailtitle">Email or Username <br><input class="inp1" type="text" name="Username" 
id="usrname2" value=""></p>
<p class="passtitle">Password<br><input type="password" name="Password" id="pass2"    
class="inp2"></p>
<input type="checkbox" class="check1">
<div class="txt1">Remember</div>
<div class="txt2">Me</div>
<img src="signinbtn.svg" class="signinbtn" onclick="verify();" >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Sign%20Up/index2.html" class="link1"><p>You don't have an  
account? Sign up </p></a>
<a href="" class="link2"><p>Forgot your password?</p></a>
</div>
 </form>
<aside class="bg">
<img src="bgblue.svg">
</aside>
 </body>
</html>
```

and here's my code for the js linked to both login and sign up page :

```
var mydb = openDatabase("accounts", "0.1", "Testing  Database", 1024 * 1024);
if (window.openDatabase) {



//create the  table using SQL for the database using a transaction
mydb.transaction(function(t) {
t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mailusr VARCHAR(50),
usrname VARCHAR(50), pass VARCHAR(100))");
});

} else {
alert("WebSQL is not supported by your browser!");
}


//function to output the list of cars in the database
function updateDrafts(transaction, results) {
//initialise the listitems variable
var listitems = "";
//get the list holder ul
var listholder = document.getElementById("drafts");

//clear the list of drafts ul
listholder.innerHTML = "";

var i;
//Iterate through the results
for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
//Get the current row from database
var row = results.rows.item(i);

listholder.innerHTML += "<li>" + row.mailusr + " - " + row.usrname + " - " + row.pass + "(<a   
href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteDraft(" + row.id + ");'>Delete this account</a>)";
}
}

//function to get the list of accounts from the database

function outputDrafts() {
//check to ensure the mydb object has been created
if (mydb) {

mydb.transaction(function(t) {
t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM mydb", [], updateDrafts);
});
} else {
alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
}
}
//function to add account

function addDraft() {
//check to ensure the mydb object has been created
if (mydb) {
//get the values of user and pass text inputs
var mailusr = document.getElementById("mailusr").value;
var usrname = document.getElementById("usrname").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;

//Test to ensure that the user has filled all the form
if (mailusr !== "" && usrname !== "" && pass !== "" && pass == pass1) {
//Insert the user entered details into database
mydb.transaction(function(t) {
t.executeSql("INSERT INTO mydb (mailusr, usrname, pass) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [mailusr, usrname,  
pass]);
outputDrafts();
});
} else if (mailusr !== "" && usrname !== "" && pass !== "" && pass !== pass1) {
alert("Your password does not match with your confirmation");
}
else{
alert("You need to fill all fields");
}

}}
var link = document.getElementById("adduser");

link.onclick = function () { alert(1)
addDraft();

};
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length, i;
msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
alert(results.rows.item(i).log );
}

}, null);
});
```

i can't somehow extract value by id in login page it said  index.html:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of null
    at verify (index.html:12)
!
i need to manage somehow to get the database details like username and password to verify if the account of the user or not in the database created in sign up page
thanks in advance. Im a beginner in javascript and websql :D .

Comment: You should never validate credentials on the client side.  The client side is insecure, and totally within the control of the user.  Smart users can use the browser developer tools to inspect code and set debugger points to inspect your logic to either find out what values variables hold, and can also change them.  Your credential validation should **always** be in the server side.  That is, if you're serious about it.

Comment: I did it without hash and salt just for testing im still working on the part of the condition before going to that part.

Comment: That does not change the fact that a client user can add breakpoints, see what hashed value you are trying to match against, and change their variables on the fly to force the logic to be true.  Again, serious credential validation should never be done on the client side.

Comment: It's fairly difficult to read your code the way it is formatted. You'll get better responses if you use indentation that makes reading easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

- Your input fields have `id="usrname2"` and `id="pass2"` but your JavaScript calls for`getElementById("usrname")` and `getElementById("pass")` These elements simply don't exist. Change the Id of your fields and it will return values
- You call `openDatabase` before you actually check if it is available, you might want to swap the lines
- never **ever ever**, even for testing store passwords in clear. Use hash and salt to keep them secure. Make it a habit.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try it now .

Comment: i changed the id in html but still give me and alert input of user doesnt exists so the first condition didnt work

Comment: "never ever ever, even for testing store passwords in clear. Use hash and salt to keep them secure. Make it a habit." <= This should actually say **never ever validate credentials on the client**.  You should never expose your credential validation to the clients.  Clients are untrustworthy, and it is always possible to inspect the code, set breakpoints, and find out what the passwords are.